# How to mock the constructor pytest

Tags: python-3.x, object, constructor, mocking, pytest

The classes are defined as follows-

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):
            self.__client = ManagerClient()
            self.__data = None
    
    def get_data(self):
        if self.__data is None:
            self.__get_password()
        return self.__data

    def __get_password(self):
            self.__password = self.__client.fetch_secret()
        


class ManagerClient:
     def fetch_secret():
         pass
```

I want to unit test get_data(), since the constructor of User class is initializing the object of manager client and that object is used later to call fetch_secret(), how should I mock?

Comment: Also I want to write unit test for __get_password? How should I mock self.__client.fetch_secret()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically when testing the `get_data` method for a unit-test we are not concerned about `__get_password` or its implementation. We simply want to test the various logical arms of `get_data`. Following that line of thinking we would simply mock `__get_password` and its action. If we wanted to test `__get_password` we would use a separate test for this.

Another thing to note is because you use double underscores for your attributes and methods they become textually replaced with `_classname__attribute`. That is why we patch and mock using this verbiage as shown below. You can see more about that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).

Also as a side note your `get_data` function is not fundamentally sound. It has two different return types based on its logic, it can either return something or set an attribute on the object, that is considered bad practice.

Given the following project structure:

```
stackoverflow/
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── users.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_users.py
```

The tests we would write are shown below.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

from mypackage.users import User


@patch("mypackage.users.ManagerClient")
def test_get_data_valid(mock_client):
    expected = "fizz"
    klass = User()

    klass._User__data = expected
    actual = klass.get_data()
    assert actual == expected


@patch("mypackage.users.ManagerClient")
@patch.object(User, "_User__get_password")
def test_get_data_none(mock_pwd, mock_client):
    klass = User()
    klass.get_data()

    mock_pwd.assert_called_once()


@patch("mypackage.users.ManagerClient")
def test_get_password(mock_client):
    mock_client.configure_mock(
        **{
            "fetch_secret.return_value": "buzz",
            "return_value": mock_client
        }
    )

    klass = User()
    klass._User__get_password()

    assert klass._User__password == "buzz"

======================================= test session starts ========================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: ***/stackoverflow
collected 3 items                                                                                  

tests/test_users.py ...                                                                      [100%]

======================================== 3 passed in 0.06s =========================================
```

As requested we mock `ManagerClient` in every test so that it does not actually get initialized. This is achieved by [patching](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) the relevant class and methods. We also test the `__get_password` method by setting a return value for `fetch_secret` that we can test against. The reason why we make the `mock_client` return itself in the final test is when you you initialize a `Mock` object, it returns a new one. To keep things simple we just set the return value of the `Mock` to itself that way we don't have to create a new object.

Comment: I don't want to initiate the object of ManagerClient, and this line here "klass = User()" will execute the init() and initiate ManagerClient.

Comment: And also what if I want to test __get_password? How should I mock self.__client.fetch_secret()?

Comment: consider marking this as solved if this answered your question

Comment: Please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66516824/mocking-exception-pytest